# centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) is not getting called in nested class

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am trying to detect BLE devices with the code below. The problem with the code below is that the centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) is not being called automatically. I am restricted to put the code inside the "class func" because of the development software that generates the code for xcode.

Why does the code below not work and how can I fix the problem?

```
import CoreBluetooth
import UIKit

class X {

   class func testX() {

      class t: UIViewController, CBPeripheralDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

          var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
          var peripheral: CBPeripheral!

          func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
              if central.state != .poweredOn {
                  print("power is off")
              } else {
                 print("power is on")
                 centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
              }
          }

          func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
               print(peripheral)
          }

          override func viewDidLoad() {
              print("bbbbbbb")
              super.viewDidLoad()
              centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
          }
      }

      let x = t()
      x.viewDidLoad()

   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you are doing `let x = t()`, and that's a local var, that will be deallocated too soon.

Comment: Also you should never call `viewDidLoad` yourself. You can call `loadViewIfNeeded`

Comment: @Larme If the local variable is deallocated too soon, what other methodes can be used to keep the nested class alive so it can call the function?

Comment: @Paulw11 If I understand you correctly the code line `x.viewDidLoad()` must be changed to `x.loadViewIfNeeded()`.